# Android Canvas restore not working after translate

Tags: android, canvas

I'm developing a 2D Android application using Canvas. I have several screens, and each one of them have a different coordinate origin. To implement this, I'm currently using Canvas.translate(x, y). When the application starts, I call canvas.save() to store the original state. When I move to a screen, I need to reset the canvas translation and then apply a new one, so the new translation is relative to the original 0,0. Basically when entering a new screen, I call:

```
canvas.restore();      //to undo the current translation
canvas.save();         //to save again the original state of canvas
canvas.translate(x, y) //to apply the needed translation
```

I works just fine for the first screen, but for the second, apparently the call to restore() isn't rolling back the translation and the translations are being made relative to the previous one.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the order of the save and restore calls is wrong. Save should always be called before restore function. You could simply do canvas.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0). This resets the transform matrix to its original form, but keeps the other context vars intact.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The order of the calls to restore() and save() is correct. Calling them in the wrong order throws an exception. Also, there's no such method like canvas.setTransform. Did you mean canvas.setMatrix ?

Comment: Umm im mixing technologies here. I meant android HTML5 canvas. sorry for that. Anyway, on Android canvas you have the setMatrix method that does just that. Try setting an identity matrix, that should work.

Comment: And dont forget to call restore after the last paint of each screen, as graphic contexts work as a stack.